# How to change "Call To +1800090098" in TopStore pro theme

Tags: widgets, frontpage

I'm looking for a way to change the text in the lower menu row (on right side) in a page with TopStore pro (theme).

An example of the theme is at
https://themehunk.com/wp-themes/top-store-multi-vendor

where the text is "Call to +99-987654321"

Comment: That's very theme specific.  Since it's a pro theme, you'll probably get the best answer with their support team or forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, from the theme-modifier page

Go through menu

Layout > Header > Main Header

Then

Call To Text / Call To Number